# Data Not Inserting into SQLite DB

Tags: java, sql, sqlite

I have an issue where data is not being inserted into the DB because the error log says no such column called columntotal exists, which is true, but columntotal is a variable that I am trying to pass into a table called "purchases" in a column called "total". Do I have the insertion statement constructed wrong?

```
public double calculateTotal() {
    double columntotal = 0;
    Cursor cursor1 = db.rawQuery(
    "SELECT SUM(price) FROM purchases", null);
    if(cursor1.moveToFirst()) {
        columntotal = cursor1.getDouble(0);
    }
    cursor1.close();

    return columntotal;
}

public void insertTotal() {
    db.rawQuery("INSERT INTO purchases(total) VALUES(columntotal)", null);
}
```

Comment: `INSERT` is not a query. Use `execSQL`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes it is wrong. that is one way to manage this:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO purchases(total)"
           + "VALUES ( ?)";
db.execSQL(sql, new String[]{YOUR_VALUE});
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply! This helped tremendously!

Answer (score 0):

You have to build the string first:

```
String insertQuery = "INSERT INTO purchases(total)"
       + "VALUES ( ?)";
```

and then execute this query.